# String removed after constructor initialize on if statement on C++

Tags: c++, string, constructor, scope, initialization

I'm experiencing a extrange behaviour on C++ (MVS 2010) when initializing on constructor a class called ManageRenderListenerCommand. That is implemented as a Command design patter, where ManageRenderListenerCommand command is one of the concrete commands.

The place I call ManageRenderListenerCommand

```
void Mediator::change(Negotiator* negotiator, NegotiatorEvent& negotiatorEvent){
    ICommand* command = NULL;
    if(negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("addToViewport")){
        command = static_cast<ICommand*> (&AddToViewportCommand(mCameraManager, mSceneCreator, mEngine));
    }else if (negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("manageRenderListener")){
        command = static_cast<ICommand*> (&ManageRenderListenerCommand(mObserverRegistry, mEngine, negotiatorEvent.getMessage()));
    }

    //Execute the created command
    if (command) command->execute();
}
```

As you can see in the code, ManageRenderListener receives a string, in that case this string contains the word add that is contained on the NegotiatorEvent class (`negotiatorEvent.getMessage()`).

The problem is, on the constructor, I take the string on an private member, but debugging I can see after the assgnation and casting it is removed and reinitialized to "". I have tried static_cast, dynamic_cast. To give a clue, I think it's a visibility problem but I don't know how to manage it.

```
}else if (negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("manageRenderListener")){
    //Here mMessage = ""
    command = static_cast<ICommand*> (&ManageRenderListenerCommand(mObserverRegistry, mEngine, negotiatorEvent.getMessage()));
    //Here mMessage is again "" instead of add
}
```

ManageRenderListener.cpp

```
#include "ManageRenderListenerCommand.h"

ManageRenderListenerCommand::ManageRenderListenerCommand(
    OgreRenderObserverRegistry* observerRegistry, 
    OgreEngine* engine,
    string message):
        mObserverRegistry(observerRegistry),
        mEngine(engine),
        mMessage(message){
}

void ManageRenderListenerCommand::execute(){
    if (mMessage.compare("add") == 0){
        mEngine->addRenderListener(mObserverRegistry->getCachedObserver());
    }else if (mMessage.compare("detach") == 0){
        mEngine->detachRenderListener(mObserverRegistry->getCachedObserver());
    }
}
```

If you need more details ask for it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does getMessage return?

Comment: Are you aware, that you pass along the address of a temporary object?  Try to get the command with `new ManageRenderListenerCommand`

Comment: Also, if `ManageRenderListenerCommand` inherits from `ICommand`, you should use dynamic_cast. Make sure dynamic type information is available.

Comment: `getMessage()` is an inline member function so it's on the .h. It only does a return statement. `inline string getMessage(){return mMessage; }`

Comment: How can I check dynamic type information?

Comment: In VS2012, you would compile with the flag `/GR` or "project Configuration Properties -> c/c++ -> Language -> Enable Run-Time Type Information". I don't know how to do it on other IDEs/compilers.

Comment: To elaborate on what scones said, `(&ManageRenderListenerCommand(mObserverRegistry, mEngine, negotiatorEvent.getMessage())` creates a temporary... using it afterwards is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @jt234 Why should one use `dynamic_cast` when casting **up**? That cast will always work and is resolvable at compile time. `dynamic_cast` is for casting *down* or *across*.

Comment: @Angew To be honest, I don't see why a cast is needed at all.

Comment: @jt234 Then why did you suggest one?

Comment: @Angew, I was trying to point out that in order to cast within an inheritance tree, one should use dynamic cast. Somewhy, it didn't occur to me at that time that the cast could be avoided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo're using a dangling pointer. The object construction you're using creates a temporary object, which is destroyed when the full expression (the `static_cast`) ends. You still have a pointer to where it was (in `command`), but the object itself has already been destroyed.

You need to create the command in a way to have it persist until in call to `execute()`. If the code is as you've shown, you could simply do this:

```
if(negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("addToViewport")){
    AddToViewportCommand(mCameraManager, mSceneCreator, mEngine).execute();
}else if (negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("manageRenderListener")){
    ManageRenderListenerCommand(mObserverRegistry, mEngine, negotiatorEvent.getMessage()).execute();
}
```

If there are more steps in between the creation and the call to `execute()`, you will probably have to create the command dynamically:

```
void Mediator::change(Negotiator* negotiator, NegotiatorEvent& negotiatorEvent){
    ICommand* command = NULL;
    if(negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("addToViewport")){
        command = new AddToViewportCommand(mCameraManager, mSceneCreator, mEngine);
    }else if (negotiatorEvent.matchEvent("manageRenderListener")){
        command = new ManageRenderListenerCommand(mObserverRegistry, mEngine, negotiatorEvent.getMessage());
    }

    //Execute the created command
    if (command) command->execute();

    delete command;
}
```

If you have access to C++11, use `std::unique_ptr<ICommand>` for `command` instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: Why here is not needed the dynamic cast?

Comment: @Feantury I assume the concrete command classes are derived from `ICommand` (if not, your original `static_cast` wouldn't have worked either). C++ has an implicit conversion from pointer-to-derived-class to pointer-to-base-class (and it's a very common thing), so doing it explicitly is actually syntactic noise.

Comment: Yes, it's derived because of command pattern requirements. Ok, I didn't know about this implicit conversion (It wasn't giving me errors so I suposed). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is initialize a command that takes a string in the c'tor;
What you actually do is force the command to be the address of the string itself..
You need to create a new object with the operator 'new', if you've already matched the type of command, you should be able to initiate the specific command and give it the string in the c'tor like:

```
command = new SomeICommand(ManageRenderListenerCommand(mObserverRegistry, mEngine, negotiatorEvent.getMessage());
```

Comment: `command = new (SomeICommand)( (ManageRenderListenerCommand(mObserverRegistry, mEngine, negotiatorEvent.getMessage()));` - this woudldn't compile - the `ManageRenderListenerCommand` you create is still a temporary; your `new` needs to be right up in front of it.

Comment: of course (SomeICommand) is to be replaced.. I'll remove the () if it is confusing

Comment: that's still not right... there won't be a `SomeICommand` other than `ManageRenderListenerCommand`... it is that that needs to be `new`ed... at best your code above would become `new ManageRenderListenerCommand(ManageRenderListenerCommand(...))` and pointlessly copy from the stack-based temporary to the heap-allocated instance.

Comment: No, because his function returns a string, and the point was to save it